# Intercome Visitor auto message not showing up

Tags: intercom

I created a landing page in Marketo and want a intercom visitor auto message to pop up upon opening. I created the message and set it so it appears if the url contains a certain something but nothing pops up on the page. 
Do you I need to add an extra bit of code on the landing page?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the page itself it's hard to determine what exactly might be happening in this case. A common snag can happen is if you're embedding JavaScript directly on to a landing page (vs. embedding it into a template or inside a tag container) is that you'll get a CDATA wrapper around your code, which can wreak havoc. I know with other platforms (such as Socedo) I've had to do a split of code where most of the main code is on the template or tag container and there's just a small bit that can go on the page itself.